# Fiber ring resonators versus microresonators

Tags: optics, resonance, fiber-optics, coherence, laser-cavity

> Fiber ring resonators made of multimode fiber are capable of supporting multiple spatial modes. Even fiber ring resonators made of single mode fiber can, under favorable conditions, support a few modes.
>
> Are there any other resonator types that can support several spatial modes?

My understanding is that, microresonators that support whispering-gallery modes (e.g. microdisks and microspheres) are single mode. Is that correct?

Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no. It essentially depends on what precise definitions you choose to use for several fuzzy terms in your question, but the generic answer is mostly no.

The reason is that ring resonators' whispering-gallery modes can also include radial excitations, which roughly look like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

These radial excitations take on exactly the same role as higher modes in a fiber, with roughly the same physics (i.e. different dispersion, and so on).

If you want to re-define the term "whispering-gallery mode" to rule out these modes, or you only want to consider configurations where these radial excitations are not addressed through some suitable physical mechanism, though, then you can indeed bend the answer over into 'yes', but that's more from bending semantics and restricting your attention (much like decreeing that you are only going to consider single-mode fibers) rather than the physics itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have a follow up question. Can microresonators, in principal, host the same amount of modes as fiber ring resonators? Do ring resonators have any advantages when it comes to the number of modes that they support?

Comment: I don't know of any useful, objective, universal measure of 'number of modes'. The comparison between the two types is deep into the engineering and depends on what you want to do and the details of the context.

Comment: Thanks. I know that for fibers there are approximate formulas that give the number of supported modes, I'm not sure if the same is true with free-space microresonators. With more modes (more refractive indexes) you have more 'degrees of freedom', and that's what I was trying to compare between the two types of resonators.

Comment: Those exist for fibers, but they depend on the frequency. For disks you could in principle cook up a similar measure, but it would include a whole bunch of modes that you would not want to tag as whispering-gallery modes -- and with no clear-cut line between the two. I don't think what you want to do can be done well in any way other than tackling the complexity head-on.